# Kentico 8.2 content locking

Tags: locking, kentico

We have a situation where the 'Check Out', 'Check In' and 'Save' buttons have disappeared from Admin: Pages -> Page/Design/Forms tabs.  Users trying to access this all have admin rights and Settings -> Content -> Content Management -> 'Use check-in/check-out:' is checked.  Content Staging/Logging is enabled (if that has any relevance).  What could cause this?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try Resigning your macros, I've seen weird UI things happen because the macros messed up, including things as you described.

System -> Macros -> Signatures -> Sign all macros and "Update macro signatures"

Tell me if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Turning on "Use check-in/check-out" is one part of the solution. The other is putting documents under a workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, good to know!  It actually ended up being a change in one of the CSS files the caused the buttons to not display.